# Value of $\mathbb{E}(\frac{1}{aX+b})$?

Tags: expected-value

There are rules e.g. $\mathbb{E}(aX+bY)=a\mathbb{E}(X)+b\mathbb{E}(Y)$, where $X$, $Y$ are random variables and $a$ and $b$ are constants.

But what about $\mathbb{E}(\frac{1}{aX+b})$?

Comment: The general rule for $\mathbb{E}[g(x)]$ for arbitrary $g$ is that there is no general rule.

Comment: [Law of the unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician)

Comment: @Glen_b: I stared at the page for a few minutes just to ensure I didn't miss anything.  Is it some sort of a parody?  Isn't that page just stating the definition/first step involved in finding $E_X[g(X)]$? :-)

Comment: @Vimal I think you have just discovered why this law is named as it is :-).  That page is relating the definition of the expectation, namely $\int_\Omega g\circ X dP$, to the formula that is often quoted as a "definition" (but is not actually one), $\int_\mathbb{R} g(x) f(x) dx$.

Comment: @whuber Casella and Berger's _Statistical Inference_ (2nd ed.) (a generally widely-referenced and highly regarded book), Definition 2.2.1 _states_ $\int_R g(x)f_X(x)dx$ and $\sum g(x_i)p(x_i)$ as the _definition_ of $E[g(X)]$, cites Ross's _A First Course in Probability_ (3rd ed.) as a source of the sobriquet "Law of the Unconscious Statistician" and snarkily remarks "We do not find this amusing." An exercise at the end of Chapter 2 asks for a proof that if $Y=g(X)$, then $\int_R yf_Y(y)dy$ has the same value as $\int_R g(x)f_X(x)dx$ but only for $g(x)$ being a monotone increasing function.

Comment: @Dilip I respect the popularity argument; but any book that also "defines" a random variable without any mention of measurability (Definition 1.4.1) has made a willful decision to avoid, or otherwise circumvent, all discussion of such technical niceties--as announced on the first page of the first chapter. Thus, its subsequent "definitions" must be understood as being less than general or rigorous. Sometimes the lack of generality is acknowledged (as in the remark at the end of section 1.6), but frequently it is not.

Comment: @Vimal As far as definitions go, it depends on whose definitions you look at. I realize that a number of authors do present that as a definition of $E(g(X))$ but it seems an odd thing to call a definition, since one can arrive at the result from more basic considerations. (The specific name used is something of a joke, of course, though it seems apt.) My linking to it is not a joke, since - on the revelation that X is binomial in a comment somewhere - that's actually how one could compute it in the OP's particular instance (for values of $(a,b)$ that don't make for any obvious simplifications)

Comment: @whuber  Hmmm I was under the impression that the Casella and Berger book was supposed to be able to serve as a text for a one-year course for advanced undergraduate students in statistics (or a first-year graduate course).  Ross's book does not even have a formal _definition_ of a random variable, but still manages to point out the reason for the sobriquet "law of the unconscious statistician", viz., there are two different "definitions" of the expectation of the random variable $Y = g(X)$, and somewhere, some one (presumably not C & B) needs to say that both definitions give the same value.

Comment: @Dilip You're right--that's what C&B claim. Whether the text provides an adequate background for such students will depend on the nature of the program they are in. I'm just suggesting that this book might not be the best authority to use when citing mathematical definitions, because it was not its aim to provide that kind of generality or rigor. The (stated) aim was to develop the statistical elements of the subject using "statistical" reasoning rather than "mathematical" reasoning. What they chose to emphasize and overlook is interesting; thank your for bringing it to our attention.

Answer (score 8):

If $\left|\frac{a}{b}X\right|<1$ (almost surely) **and** $X$ has all its moments such that the following converges, then:

$$E[\frac{1}{aX+b}]=\frac{1}{b}(1-E[aX/b]+E[(aX/b)^2]-E[(aX/b)^3]+\cdots),$$

which can be calculated if you know the moments of $X$. On the other hand, occasionally it's a reasonable approximation to cutoff the series, say:

$$E[\frac{1}{aX+b}]\approx\frac{1}{b}(1-E[aX/b]),$$

which holds when $X$ is small.

Such techniques are actually quite useful in other areas, especially when you know one random variable is dominated by another in size. [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_expansions_for_the_moments_of_functions_of_random_variables).

Comment: This is a nice contribution to the thread--but you need to assume something a little stronger; namely, $|aX| \lt |b|$ a.s.. You also need to fix your formula, which is incorrect: I believe it should equal $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{-1}{k}\frac{a^k}{b^{k+1}}E\left[X^k\right].$$

Comment: @whuber: whoops, dropped the b. Thanks! I don't think you need those extra binomial coefficients as it's an expansion of $1/(1+x)$.

Comment: +1 The "extra binomial coefficients" are essential.  In this case they provide the alternating signs.  For powers other than the reciprocal ($-1$) they indicate how your answer generalizes.

Answer (score 3):

OP has declined to revise the question to reflect the elaborations and questions s/he has posed in the comments. I think it's entirely sufficient to indicate that the answer to this question is simply to apply the [Law of the Unconscious Statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician). The Law states that in the discrete case,
$$
E(g(X))=\sum_A g(x)p_X(x)
$$

where $g$ is some function and $p_X(x)$ is the pmf of $x$ and $A=\{x:p_X(x)>0\}.$ Note that you must also check that the sum (or integral) is absolutely convergent, cf Riemann's rearrangement theorem.

Downvoters are invited to describe why this answer is incorrect.

Comment: I'm actually working on a discrete distribution.

Comment: (1) This should be stated in the the question. (2) Replace the integral with an appropriate sum.

Comment: Is $x$ in $p(x)$ and $ax$ the values that the r.v. $X$ can acquire? E.g. in binomial $x\in\{0,1\}$. And then the sum would be $\sum_x=\sum_{i=0}^1$

Comment: I don't understand your question. I think it would be beneficial to edit your original question to state (1) what problem you're trying to solve and (2) where, after applying our hints, you are stuck, Write down the problem as specifically as you can using the suggestions from our answers.

Comment: I'm not seeing how this answers the question...

Comment: If you have a positive distribution on the non-negative integers, then, if there is a non-zero probability that $X=0$, the expectation is infinite!

Comment: OK, lets say that with probability 0.2 we have that $X=0$. Then, $1/X$ is $1/0$, which isn't defined, but can in this context often be taken as $\infty$. And, with that interpretation, the expectation of $1/X$ becomes $\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot move the expectation in the denominator if that is what you are asking. Due to [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) you would end up either understimating or overestimating the expectation, depending on the value of $\alpha$.

What I would do is try to first find the distribution of the linear transformation then of its reciprocal and finally compute the expectation of the final distribution. Equivalently, you can just use the [Law of the Unconsious Statistican](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) and avoid all this hustle.

Comment: "What I would do is try to first find the distribution of the linear transformation then of its reciprocal and finally compute the expectation of the final distribution.". I'm asking how to do this. I've already calculated $\mathbb{E}(aX+b)$

Comment: @mavavilj How do I know what distribution you are dealing with?

Comment: The binomial distribution.

Comment: @mavavilj Edit your question then.

Comment: I thought there would be formulas regardless of distribution. Such as the one's proposed by user777.

Comment: The point is that there is no general and simple formulas! We need to know the distribution of $X$, completely, only some descriptors such as the mean and variance is not enough.